# IFrame not respecting user agent

Tags: javascript, html

Inside a website I have an iframe that loads another website, like the code below :

```
<iframe style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%" src="https://www.mywebsite.com"></iframe>
```

It's working BUT the iframe does not respect the user agent. The www.mywebsite.com has specific versions for mobile and desktop, but when I open it inside the iframe in a mobile device, it will load the desktop version instead. If i open the same site directly on the URL on the same mobile device, the correct version (the mobile one) is shown.

What should I do on the iframe code to it loads the mobile version instead?

Comment: *"does not respect the user agent"* ... where and how is that determined?

Comment: @charlietfl I simply open the site with the frame on the Iphone and the desktop version is shown. If i open the same site outside the iframe, the mobile version is shown.

Comment: Simply not enough known

Comment: @delphirules — I suspect you're misdiagnosing the problem. What makes you think that `www.mywebsite.com` is explicitly checking the user-agent string sent by the browser?

Comment: @Quentin As far as i understand, if the www.mywebsite.com opens in the mobile version on the Iphone, an iframe should open exactly the same version on the Iphone and this is not happening... maybe some additional config on the iframe ?

Answer (score -2):

```
<iframe style="border: 0; width: 100vw; height: 100vh" src="https://www.mywebsite.com"></iframe>
```

Try this code instead I think it will work